# How do I block access to the root files of the subdomain with Apache?

Tags: debian, virtualhost, apache2

I have a subdomain that has index.php at its root. What I want is to block access to `https://SUB.example.com/index.php` or any other top files while letting anyone with a full URL to access to files (like another index.php in a subfolder of that subdomain)

I would like to do this under my virtualhost config instead of .htaccess because the same folder is used by another subdomain.

I am using Apache 2.4 under Debian Buster

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to limit the access to a certain path, but here's one example:

Make use of the `<Location>` tag.  For example:

```
<VirtualHost "*:80">
    DocumentRoot "/path/to/blah"
    ServerName blah.blah.blah
    <Location "/somepath">
        Require all denied
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

You could also use the `Redirect` option in the location, if you want to point the client somewhere more informational:

```
Redirect 403 /somepath /some-nice-message.html
```

Comment: The issue is this. I want to block `/index.php` but not  `/index.php/apps/somepage`

Comment: use LocationMatch with a regex that only matches what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `LocationMatch` directive, which allows specifying a regular expression as a location, like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName your.server.name
    (...)
    <LocationMatch "^/[^/]*">
       Require all denied
    </LocationMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

This will block all access which begins with a `/`, but does not contain any `/` signs, so anything in the webroot will be blocked, but any path under that will be allowed. Parameters are not considered part of the path, so calling `/index.php?/blah` will be denied as well.

However, if `AcceptPathInfo` is `On` or `Default`, then paths like `/index.php/blah` will be accepted, and will result in parsing the `php` file (in fact, any scripts which have handlers accepting PATH_INFO requests will be served this way). If it is not what you want, then you might want to disable `AcceptPathInfo`, but that may result in misbehaving PHP pages. A better solution is explicitly denying php files in the root directory (this config snippet should be used after the one above):

```
<LocationMatch "^/[^/]*\.php.*">
    Require all denied
</LocationMatch>
```

Comment: Thanks I will test this one too.